# How to create stored procedure using EXECUTE in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to create a stored procedure in mysql using execute command.

For example

```
execute('create procedure proc_name begin select 5 end');
```

how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, You need to prepare statment first and then you can execute it
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/execute.html

I think you want to develop store procedure dynamically.

try below:

```
create procedure test(proc_name varchar(100))
begin
set @s:=concat(' create procedure ',proc_name,' begin select 5 end;');
PREPARE stmt from @s;   
EXECUTE stmt;  
end
```